# Error starting Eclipse on Ubuntu, JVM terminated Exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I know, This question is repeated. But I couldn't find solution to my problem.
I do not have sudo permission on ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, so downloaded eclipse-cpp-luna-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz and jdk-8u25-linux-i586.tar.gz. set JAVA_HOME ->jdk, JRE_HOME->JRE and PATH variable to JAVAHOME/bin

Getting the below error

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/vol/users/pradeep.rajan/eclipse/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/work/pradeep.rajan/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/work/pradeep.rajan/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/work/pradeep.rajan/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/work/pradeep.rajan/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /home/work/pradeep.rajan/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 2f48018
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /vol/users/pradeep.rajan/eclipse/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/work/pradeep.rajan/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

My eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: You are using a 32 bit JDK with a 64 bit Eclipse. They must both be 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the JRE to `eclipse/jre` so eclispse can use `eclipse/jre/bin/java`!

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work..
Also, I'm getting below error
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/work/pradeep.rajan/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

Comment: What does `uname -a` write?